# Use collection as entity with type in Symfony2 form

Tags: php, symfony

Is it possible to generate select list where options will be retrieved from database and there will be option (with JS) to multiply field ?

I've copied my code, maybe it will help.

```
$builder->add('device', 'collection', array(
    'type' => 'entity',
    'label' => ' ',
    'options' => array(
         'class' => 'TrashTrashAdminBundle:DeviceType',
         'property' => 'name',
         'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
             return $er->createQueryBuilder('d')
                 ->where('d.isLighting = 1');
          },
     ),
     'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control device')
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to work with `collection` field type in way as you would work with `entity` field type. You should change `collection` for `entity`:

```
$builder->add('device', 'entity', array(                
    'options' => array(
        'class' => 'TrashTrashAdminBundle:DeviceType',
        'property' => 'name',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('d')
                    ->where('d.isLighting = 1');
            },
    ),
    'attr' => array(
        'class' => 'form-control device'
    ))
);
```

After the select box is generated, you can make changes, which you mentioned, at your will.